# Access, how can I find last name which has lower case in the first letter?

Tags: ms-access, replace, detect

How can I find and replace to uppercase for the column of last name which has lower case in the first letter and comma between the name or space before the name?

For example:

Last Name

Carr

palio

li

[space] West

Find palio, li, West and change to Palio and Li and West

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will remove a leading space and/or change the first character to Upper case.  Not sure what you mean about "comma between the name"  is that like 'doe, John'?

You can add your own selection criteria (I only check to make sure not blank field).

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Name1 = IIf(Left([Name1],1)=" ",UCase(Mid([name1],2,1)) & Mid([name1],3),UCase(Left([name1],1)) & Mid([name1],2))
WHERE (((Table1.Name1)<>''));
```

Comment: Im sorry but do I put the whole above code(UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Name1 = IIf(Left([Name1],1)=" ",UCase(Mid([name1],2,1)) & Mid([name1],3),UCase(Left([name1],1)) & Mid([name1],2))
WHERE (((Table1.Name1)<>''));) to "update to" column? because it seems Im doing something wrong.. keeps getting me the error

Answer (score 0):

I would trim then proper case. More reliable then writing an if statement:

```
UPDATE table SET table.lName = StrConv(trim(table.lName),vbProperCase)
```

Comment: Im sorry but do I put the whole above code(UPDATE table SET table.lName = StrConv(trim(table.lName),vbProperCase)) to "update to"

Comment: The above 'code' (in both answers) is actually a query that you can execute to make changes.  Will the 'Last Name' field ever have a value like "Henry VIII"? of 'Jones, III'?  If so, the StrConv will improperly change those to 'Viii' and 'Iii'.

Comment: Good point Wayne. I didn't think about that. I guess you also have McGregor and other names like that it could effect. You can run either of these by going to "Create >> Query Design >> close the table window that comes up. Right click the blank space >> SQL View >> Paste in the code. Then run.